# Parsing and iterating String to arraylist

Tags: java

I have a String with value as:

> String lstr = [12.88, 77.56],[12.81, 77.7156]

....so on

I need to parse and iterate it and somehow substitute the values as :

```
final ArrayList<Coordinate> points = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        points.add(new Coordinate(12.88, 77.56));
        points.add(new Coordinate(12.81, 77.7156));
```

i tried converting string to List and then iterating it using for loop, but it is not working, either it goes out of bound or extra square bracket throws an exception.
What is the best way to parse, format and iterate a string like this?

Comment: show us what you have tried and what the errors are, or do you just want someone to do it for you?

Comment: What do you mean " extra square bracket throws an exception " ? And show us your loop code! What exception do you get ?

Comment: You first line is not proper Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like in the example below. Note you can improve your regex to check for spaces etc.:

```
String lstr = "[12.88, 77.56],[12.81, 77.7156]";

List<Coordinate> cors = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

String []coordinates = lstr.split("\\],\\[");

for(String cordinate:coordinates)
{
    String []xy = cordinate.split(",");
    cors.add(new Coordinate(xy[0],xy[1]));
}
System.out.println(cors);
```